# .htaccess redirect no-parameter to default-parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using the following rewrite rule for  **language indication** and **clean url** purpose.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

When no language parameter is given, the website will not display correctly. So when a user requests *www.mydomain.com/products* instead of *www.mydomain.com/en/products* the website will mallfunction.

The solution would be a .htaccess configuration that would redirect the user to *www.mydomain.com/en* by default when no language parameter is given (like *www.mydomain.com*). How do I perform an external .htaccess redirect to *www.mydomain.com/en/* when the user requests *www.mydomain.com/* ?

Comment: _“When no language parameter is given, the website will not display correctly.”_ – why? What kind of carelessly and neglectfully written script is this, that it can not determine default values for such a parameter itself?

Comment: One written by a beginner programmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# lang & page
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]

# Only lang
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]

# no lang -> default "en" lang
RewriteRule ^$ en [R=301,L]
```

This way, you have to check lang in your php.

Or you can use `(en|fr|es)` for example in your htaccess instead of `([a-z]{2})`

Comment: That did the trick!

My website was actually stored in a subfolder so I had to change RewriteBase / to RewriteBase /subfolder/

Comment: It rewrites mydomain.com/subfolder/ to mydomain.com/subfolder/en/ 

There is one slight problem though:

When clicking on a link <a href="contact"> I'm expecting the browser to open mydomain.com/subfolder/en/contact

but somehow it erases /en/ and opens mydomain.com/subfolder/contact

Comment: Disregard that. Rewrote like this and fixed it:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /twinstrailers/

# lang & page
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]

# Only lang
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]

# no lang -> default "en" lang
RewriteRule ^$ en/ [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong regex in your rule, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Your `/?` creates duplicate content

Comment: It creates duplicate content because you can access to url.com/something/ and url.com/something too. The problem is both are not the same: one is a directory, and other is a file. For example, Google will consider that as duplicate content. That's why it's better to add or remove a trailing slash with one rule in the htaccess

Comment: Well to begin with rule doesn't create URL. URLs are created by the web developers. This is just an internal rewrite rule that provides flexibility to a web developer to choose URL scheme with or without trailing slash.

Comment: That's what i said. With or without trailing slash is not the same ! Thinking that is evil, good for duplicate content.

Comment: Yes not the same but I guess you are still missing my point. Rule is not creating duplicate links it is up to a web developer to maintain a particular URL scheme throughout the site.

Comment: You don't get my point either. With your `/?` it allows to access url with or without trailing slash. This generates duplicate content. Here's an exemple among many others: http://forum.cs-cart.com/topic/24832-missing-trailing-slashes-in-url-are-causing-duplicate-content-issue/

Comment: I do get that very well. `/?$` only gives flexibility to a web developer to choose either scheme it doesn't create any duplicate links by itself.

Comment: I agree but it's a bad practice to use it, especially when you give a solution here on stackoverflow, without knowing if OP has something to take care of trailing slash. If you use `/?` without doing anything, you can access your url with or without slash. It DOES generate duplicate content (when one same content can be accessed by multiple urls)

Comment: I have already written what I had to. I consider anything that gives flexibility to a web developer "a good practice". YMMV